# Two location in nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I have two SPA applications. Single for administration, it called `dashboard`, and the second for users is called `home`.

In Docker, I build each application.

```
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-home /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/home
COPY --from=build-dashboard /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard
```

In Docker container folder structure looks like this:

```
root@605813e61476:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
50x.html  dashboard  home  index.html
root@605813e61476:/usr/share/nginx/html#
```

my `nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
      alias /usr/share/nginx/html/home/;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /dashboard {
      alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # location /api {
    #   rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
    #   proxy_pass http://api:5000;
    #   proxy_redirect off;
    # }
  }
}
```

I want when a user visits `/dashboard/*` he sees `/usr/share/nginx/html/ dashboard`, and in other cases `/usr/share/nginx/html/home`. Now when I visiting `/dashboard/*` i see home app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to keep things simple. Since you have static resources in two directories, try this:

```
index index.html;

location / {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/home;
}

location /dashboard {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

Comment: This does not work ;(
My applications is SPAs and every request on `/` need to handle by `index.html` in `/usr/share/nginx/html/home` and use statics file out this directory. And all requests `/dashboard/` need to handle by `/usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/index.html` and usage own static files. In your code all request handle by `/usr/share/nginx/html/home/index.html` that's not good for me.

Comment: @Pavel did you test my configuration or not?

Comment: Yes, I tested. When I navigate to `/about` I get a 404 error. If i additing `try_files $uri /index.html;` then on `/dashboard` i get `index.html` from `/usr/share/nginx/html/home`.

Comment: And where is `about/index.html` located?

Comment: My application is SPA. `about/index.html` located in `/usr/share/nginx/html/home`